# how to copy all files from a directory and move the copy of those file to different directory in same azure blob container c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am a newbie to c# and .net and Azure developement i wanna copy all files from a directory and move the copy of those file to different directory in same azure blob container so that i can work with the copy of file when the original file is safe. But had no idea how to do so..

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment

You can use the below code to copy blobs from one directory to another directory in a same container in Azure Blob Storage:

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
var connectionString = "StorageAccountConnectionString";
string containerName = "ContainerName";
string directory1 = "SourceDirectory";
string directory2 = "TargetDirectory";
var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
var containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
foreach (BlobItem blob in containerClient.GetBlobs())
{
    if (blob.Name.Contains(directory1))
    {
        var blobUri = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
        var newBlob = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name.Replace(directory1,directory2));
        newBlob.StartCopyFromUri(blobUri.Uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient way as you download all the filenames to your device.
Instead use: `containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: directory1)`